# Problem occur when start boot repair in ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: boot, grub2

GPT detected. Please create a BIOS-Boot partition (>1MB, unformatted filesystem, bios_grub flag). This can be performed via tools such as Gparted. Then try again.
Alternatively, you can retry after activating the [Separate /boot/efi partition:] option.

Please give the solution for this error.

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? That's no error, it's maybe a consequence of trying to install Ubuntu in Legacy mode in a GPT drive. Better to boot and install in UEFI mode.

Comment: I want to upgrade grub2?

Comment: Why? What for? And what does Boot Repair has to do with it? Better [edit] and describe what the problem actually is instead of what you think is a solution...

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to follow https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DiskSpace#BIOS-Boot_or_EFI_partition_.28required_on_GPT_disks.29 .

The proper solution depends on what exactly are you trying to achieve.

If you want to boot via EFI:

- backup all your data since changing partition layout in non-proffesional way will destroy them
- `parted /dev/X` substitute X for device name that represents your drive
- create the partitions as follows: (adjust sizes and flags to match your current partitons if you want to prevent the data loss)

`Number  Start   End    Size    File system  Name                          Flags
 1      144GB   145GB  512MB   fat16        EFI System Partition          boot, esp
 2      145GB   145GB  512MB   ext4
 3      145GB   236GB  90.2GB                                             lvm`

 - format your newly created partitions: `mkfs.vfat /dev/X1` and `mkfs.ext4 /dev/X2`
 - your vfat partition represents the /boot/efi mount point
 - your ext4 partition represents the /boot mount point

Here's an example of my fstab:
UUID=15612dd9-fa37-43d5-ba89-81224473779c /boot                   ext4    defaults        1 2
UUID=9B5B-30A6          /boot/efi               vfat    umask=0077,shortname=winnt 0 2

afterwards you should be able to run the grub2-install that should take care of the rest.

If however you'd prefer to boot via (legacy) BIOS Boot then you need MBR formatted partition then try to follow the steps for the EFI but create just one partiton and mount it under /boot + populate fstab accordingly.